# How to properly clear an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321037/clearing-an-item-in-a-c-struct-array) . Now I wish to clear every element of the array without the use of setting the '\0' trick. I tried with memset, but it complains of

```
 expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘struct array’
```

here is my code:

```
    int i;  
for( i=0; i< sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) ; i++){
    memset(array[i], 0, sizeof(array[i] ) );
}
```

how to properly clear it. thanks

Comment: The error says it all, [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) expects a pointer/address and you are passing an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memset` expects a pointer (add `&`):

```
memset(&array[i], 0, sizeof(array[i] ) );
```

But if you are going to clear the entire array, you could replace the `for`-loop with:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

As a side note: You should really avoid `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. Define constant for element count. It is less error prone when you start passing arrays to functions.

Comment: the for loop (first method) works. It doesn't work for the 2nd method

Comment: @dorothy How it doesn't work? What is the declaration of `array`?

Comment: hi, after memset(), i cannot use back the array to store things , right?

Comment: @dorothy I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a static array there's no need for a `for` loop:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array)); // sizeof gives proper size of entire array if array is static.
```